# Dynamically sized TextBox that does not expand with input?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-4.5

I have been having a problem where I want the text boxes in my application to dynamically resize with the window, but not expand when a user inputs text.

However after searching it would not appear that there is a generic solution to fix all the text boxes in the application, short of adding XAML bindings for the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties of the text box.

So I created the following control to automatically lock a text boxes dimensions after a `Measure()` call:

```
<TextBox x:Class="GUI.Views.Controls.FixedTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
</TextBox>
```

---

```
public partial class FixedTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public FixedTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            UnboundDimensions();
            var measured = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
            BoundDimensions();
            return measured;
        }

        private void UnboundDimensions()
        {
            MaxWidth = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            MaxHeight = Double.PositiveInfinity;
        }

        private void BoundDimensions()
        {
            MaxWidth = ActualWidth > 0 ? ActualWidth : Double.PositiveInfinity;
            MaxHeight = ActualHeight > 0 ? ActualHeight : Double.PositiveInfinity;
        }
    }
```

This solution works fine, but I was wondering if there is maybe a better way before I go through my XAML code and change the text boxes to my custom control....?

Edit (Problem Example): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28956841/TextBoxTrouble.zip

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxTrouble.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="500">

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Label 1</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Margin="10">Some text</TextBox>

            <Label Grid.Column="3"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Label 2</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="4" 
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                     Margin="10"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap">Some multiline text</TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever had the problem you're describing. Can you post a small, complete program that demonstrates this behavior that you're describing? A `MainWindow.xaml` and `.cs` would be fine. I suspect the problem might be in the parent of the `TextBox`.

Comment: Agreed @Steve. I've never had a textbox auto expand to fill content. Something else is going on. Show us your xaml file as asked.

Comment: Here is a sample of the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28956841/TextBoxTrouble.zip

Comment: Please post code here, in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code you posted (all that was necessary to post for me to find your problem was the contents of MainWindow.xaml) is that you need to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` for your outermost `ScrollViewer`.

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxTrouble.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="500">

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" <!-- THIS LINE -->
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: Have a look at the example, you probably have to run it because the behavior is not what I expected from the XAML. I think it has something to do with using 'Grid.IsSharedSizeScope'....

Comment: I need the scroll bars in both directions sadly, otherwise it would be that simple, but the problem is also in the vertical direction, the view this is part of is sort of a container for hosting other views, some of which are quite large.

Comment: I think I'm not clear on what you're looking for. You don't want to TextBoxes to change size when text is entered, so do you need the outer-most ScrollViewer in the case that the window is resized smaller than its initial size? If so, why not simply set the height/width of the controls and be done?

Comment: That's strange behavior. While I don't have an answer, I have a hunch this has to do with your `TextBoxes` that don't have fixed size, and also have `ScrollContentPresenters` inside of them. Then these are placed into *another* `ScrollViewer`, which has another `ScrollContentPresenter`. Now, we have a container (the outer `ScrollViewer`) that's has no fixed size, and some other controls without fixed size. How does the layout manager know what to resize when? I've seen odd behavior before when one `ScrollViewer` is put into another.

Comment: Check out this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584067/use-scrollviewer-inside-another-scrollviewer

Comment: I was basically hoping there was a simple property or something I could set that would stop a control resizing based on its content, because that is the specific behavior I am looking to stop. But the three solutions seem to be custom measure code, binding max dimensions and changing the layout structure all together.