# WPF Use Scrollviewer of DataGrid instead of outer ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, scrollviewer

**Scenario:**
I have a MainWindow. Inside this MainWindow I have a Grid. Inside the grid I have some buttons and other stuff. Also I have a ScrollViewer with a ContentControl at the end of the Grid. I switch the Content of the ContentControl using MVVM. I always load a UserControl inside the Content of the ContentControl.
Inside on of these UserControls I have a Grid containing a DataGrid with VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to Auto.

```
<MainWindow>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ContentControl />
    <ScrollViewer>
<MainWindow>
```

After loading the UserControl the hierarchy would look like this:

```
<MainWindow>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ContentControl>
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
    <ScrollViewer>
<MainWindow>
```

**Problem:**
I want that the DataGrid takes Control of the scrolling, but because there is a scrollviewer around the contentcontrol, the Components around the DataGrid think, they have infinite Height, so the outer ScrollViewer takes Control of the Scroll.

**Possible solution:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584067/use-scrollviewer-inside-another-scrollviewer) I read:

> You need to set a height on the inner ScrollViewer, otherwise it'll
>   stretch as much as it needs based on it's content's size.

And in the Code example I was not able to see anything in the inner scrollbar:

> ```
> <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
>     <DataGrid />
> </ScrollViewer>
> ```

But I was able to see the following in the inner Grid definition:

> ```
> <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualHeight}">
> ```

But I cant do this, because my RootWindow is outside of this scope, because it is in a different Component (in XAML). But I learnt, that I can make a binding to an element of a parent Control, with DependencyProperties, but I don't even know if it will work, when I set the Height of the Grid to that ActualHeight of the RootWindow and secondly I don't know how to implement this DependencyProperty (I made tutorials, but I was not able to get it to work (XAML doesn't recognize my Dependency Property).

**Question:**
Is there another way (without Dependency Properties), to make the DataGrid take control of the scrolling?
If not: How can I implement this Dependency Property, so that it works in my case?

Comment: The problem is that the scollViewer gives its content unlimited expansion space so the data grid never needs to activate its scrolling,. if you set a max size on your data grid you will trigger the scrolling behaviour

Comment: Placing a scrollviewer under mainwindow is a realy bad idea in general, since you cant use Grid RowDefinition height=* anymore.
Just place it in the views that need it.