# How to make child ScrollViewer inside another (parent) ScrollViewer fill its parent

Tags: wpf

I have a disign where one ScrollViewer is embedded into another ScrollViewer.
The problem I have, is that the child ScrollViewer does not fill its parent, but always makes the parent ScrollViewer scroll.
I need to give to child ScrollViewer only the space it parent has, and then make the child scroll, if it's contents are too large to fit.

I know there is a simmilar question, but it does not help me:
[Use ScrollViewer inside another Scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584067/use-scrollviewer-inside-another-scrollviewer)

Here is the code that displays the problem:

```
 <Window
    x:Class="ScrollviewerIssue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="200"
    Height="200"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text
                </TextBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why use a ScrollViewer if you are not using the Scrolling functionality of it ? If the scrolling functionality of the parent is not used, then totally remove it.

Comment: The example is trimmed for simplicity. There are many other elements in real screnario, which make sanse for using both ScrollViewers.

Comment: In that case you have to specify the size of your child ScrollViewer. You can do that by setting the height and the width of it or you can give your RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition specific height and width...

Comment: Thanks. But what do you do, if the area for the child ScrollViewer changes, as one resizes the Window containing the ScrollViewer? I need to fill the area, not artificially limit to some standard values which make no sense on different resolution monitors, and other situations? Maybe I need to rethink the approach, if this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView is a Layout Container. Layout (eg, LinearLayout) is a View Container. How do you want to scroll, that scrolling behavior is defined by the Layout that you put inside your ScrollView.

**ScrollView is kind of interface, that does scrolling based on it's inside Layout.**

So, to put nested ScrollView, you can do something like this:

```
ScrolleView
    LinearLayout
        ScrollView
    RelativeLayout
        TextView
```